# vsftpd - Illegal PORT command

Tags: virtualbox, ftp, vsftpd

I'm using a Ubuntu Server on a VirtualBox machine. Apache and SSH are working, but FTP after successfully connect to the server and login, it sends a error message:

```
 - Command: PORT 127,0,0,1,180,221 
 - Response: 500 Illegal PORT command.
 - Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Port Forwarding:
TCP | Host Port 2100 | Guest Port 21
```

My vstpd.conf file:

```
listen=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=2005
pasv_max_port=2010
port_enable=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
ftpd_banner=Welcome.
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

Comment: Check your logs to see if they give a reason.  Also check and see what it says the IP address of the client is when you connect.  If it is your real IP address instead of 127.0.0.1, then that's the problem.

Comment: @guntbert It's already fixed, this question it's from months ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jackbenny is close...

I am running on AWS with Ubuntu here is what I did to make vsftpd behave correctly:

```
seccomp_sandbox=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
pasv_address=<(public ip) or (AWS public domain or DNS)>
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30100
port_enable=YES
```

Then you have to make sure you are allowing ports, `20,21,30000-30100` through. Keep in mind that the port choices `30000-30100` are completely arbitrary and can be whatever you want. Although, I would stick to ports above `10000` and a range of `100` or more.

Comment: Again, he's not using pssive mode.

Comment: I know that... however, certain programs will ONLY use passive mode for some commands. For example, the program I was using, I had passive explicitly set to off yet I received this error. So, I did the above and it worked.

Comment: If it had been using passive mode, then it wouldn't get a failure from the PORT command.  Passive means use the PASV command instead of PORT.

Comment: This error manifests when the FTP server changes from listening on port 21 to another, higher port. When a command is issued that uses passive mode, the server establishes a new back connection to the client. This connection extends from the server (outside the firewall boundaries) to a dynamically allocated port number on the client computer. Because the port number is not known in advance, it chooses a random port above 1023 unless specifically given a range to choose within. This port error can most definitely be caused by a command using passive when the server is not setup for passive.

Comment: Thx, it also work for aliyun.

Answer (score 5):

Did you get that error while connecting from "the outside"? In that case you might need to add your external IP to vsftpd so that it know which IP to send to it's clients when using passive mode FTP.

Try adding `pasv_address=<YOUR_IP_HERE>` to your config.

You can also try to switch your FTP-client to active mode and see if you still get the same error.

You might also need to set the port range for passiv FTP and also enabling passiv mode FTP. Try addning these lines (replace START_PORT and END_PORT with your desired ports, and also don't forget to port forward them in your router):

```
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=<START_PORT>
pasv_max_port=<END_PORT>
```

Comment: Locally. I'm still searching information about vftpd behind NAT with no luck. And yes, I switched a few times the mode, but same error appears.

Comment: I think something it's wrong here, passive mode it's from port 2005 to 2010. But FileZilla connects to port 842 (192*4+74). I restarted the service a few times.

Comment: That's for when the PASV response has the wrong address...